# mocking fields of global objects like window using jest

Tags: reactjs, dom, mocking, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to write code for a small utility class that detects change in orientation. Unfortunately, the only way I found to access these fields `window.orientation` and `window.screen.orientation`

I can see that `window.orientation` is deprecated. The alternative I found is the experimental detection api that is not supported on Safari. And so I decided to stick to the deprecated apis for now till I find something better.

Now the other challenge I am facing is whilst mocking access to these readonly field
[image]

I am facing a similar problem when trying same approach with `window.orientation`.

Essentially properties we are trying to alter are readonly properties.

What is the correct approach in this situation?

Note the deprecation warning for window.orientation that I see is present in lib.dom.d.ts

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to do this.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
export function main() {
  const orientation = window.screen.orientation;
  return orientation.type;
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { main } from './';

describe('63570675', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    Object.defineProperty(window.screen, 'orientation', {
      value: { type: 'landscape-primary' },
    });
    const actual = main();
    expect(actual).toEqual('landscape-primary');
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/63570675/index.test.ts
  63570675
    ✓ should pass (5ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.292s, estimated 14s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/63570675

Comment: Thanks @slideshowp2 I am sure this will work. I was hoping for something more idiomatic then actually modifying the global object. Since nothing like that has turned up, I guess what you have suggested is the only way forward.